# downgrading packages in debian

Tags: debian, package-management, apt

I have Debian stable disribution installed on my computer. Once I installed some packages from testing but now it causes some troubles so I would like to downgrade them.
I've tried next commands:

```
apt-get --reinstall install  `apt-show-versions | grep newer | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | tr '\n' ' '`
```

this doesn't work because apt tries to retrieve the same versions of packages and complains that it can't download them because I now have no sources for testing packages in `sources.list`

```
apt-get -t squeeze  install  `apt-show-versions | grep newer | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | tr '\n' ' '`
```

doesn't work either. Writes that the newest versions of packages have already installed. 
I thought `-t sqeeze` forces apt to install packages from stable.

Anyway how can I solve this task?

Comment: wouldn't it work if you add the testing sources to sources.list again, purge the testing applications, remove the sources and install again?

Answer (score 3):

I use this:

```
for p in $(apt-show-versions|grep "newer than version in archive"|cut -d\  -f1); do apt-get install $p=$(apt-cache show $p|grep ^Version|tail -1|cut -d\  -f2); done
```

(There is a double space after both `-d\`.)

Comment: Ohh man, thanks i love you, i've replaced apt for aptitude and i works very very nice. Kisses !!

Answer (score 0):

As @wullxz said. You can do that by purging the new packages, removing or commenting out the unstable repo from the `sources list`, installing the old packages then, uncomment or add the unstable repo again to `sources.list` if you want to use some other packages from it.

- Purge new package:

> sudo apt-get purge my-package

- Edit `sources.list` and comment out the testing repo:

> sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list

- Install old stable package again:

> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install my-package

- (Optional) Use the testing repo again (as aforementioned) if u need to and, lock the version for that particular package temporarily:

> # uncomment the testing repo from `sources.list`
>
> sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
>
> # Lock the current version of the package.
>
> echo "my-package hold" | dpkg --set-selections

- If you would like to remove the lock and install the testing package again:

> echo "my-package install" | dpkg --set-selections